# Issues on following links in scrapy

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I want to crawl a blog which has several categories of websites . Starting navigating the page from the first category, my goal is to collect every webpage by following the categories . I have collected the websites from the 1st category but the spider stops there , can't reach the 2nd category .

An example draft :

[image: example draft]

my code :

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import Rule, CrawlSpider
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from final.items import DmozItem

    class my_spider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'heart'
    allowed_domains = ['greek-sites.gr']
    start_urls = ['http://www.greek-sites.gr/categories/istoselides-athlitismos']

    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(r'.*categories/.*', )), callback='parse', follow=True),)


    def parse(self, response):
        self.logger.info('Hi, this is an item page! %s', response.url)
        categories = response.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "categories")]/text()').extract()
        for category in categories:
            item = DmozItem()
            item['title'] = response.xpath('//a[contains(text(),"gr")]/text()').extract() 
            item['category'] = response.xpath('//div/strong/text()').extract() 
        return item
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is simple: the `callback` has to be different than `parse`, so I suggest you name your method `parse_site` for example and then you are ready to continue your scraping.

If you make the change below it will work:

```
rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(r'.*categories/.*', )), callback='parse_site', follow=True),)

def parse_site(self, response):
```

The reason for this is described [in the docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Rule):

> When writing crawl spider rules, avoid using `parse` as callback, since the `CrawlSpider` uses the `parse` method itself to implement its logic. So if you override the `parse` method, the crawl spider will no longer work.

Comment: Yep thats it . I had changed the name before but it couldn't work . Maybe i had issues with my rules but now it works . Thanks !